# global this.state is not accessible inside renderContent or renderHeader in (Accordion NativeBase)

Tags: react-native, native-base

### Issue Description

As the title say , the global this.state is not accessible inside renderContent or renderHeader in Accordion

```
renderContent(item)
{
   console.log(this.state.anyVariable);
   // Red page error => Cannot read property 'anyVariable' of undefined
}
```

#### Expected behaviour

To log the anyVariable value

#### Actual behaviour

it see this.state as undefined !!

#### Is the bug present in both iOS and Android or in any one of them?

I only tested it inside IOS

Comment: have you bound `this` to the function via `.bind(this)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use arrow function,

```
renderContent = item => {
{
   console.log(this.state.anyVariable);
   // Red page error => Cannot read property 'anyVariable' of undefined
}
```

or use `bind`.

Comment: thank you!  this really helped me out.

Can you explain WHY it works with an arrow function?